# Space after decimal comma in math mode

Tags: math-mode

This is actually my first time using Math mode in earnest. Without being able to put a finger on it, I am not really happy with the whole document (fractions are rather ugly, for starters). My main concern, however, is the space after the decimal comma – in math mode only. I appreciate your suggestions.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[no-math]{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Noto Sans}
\setsansfont{Noto Sans}
\usepackage[italic]{mathastext}

\usepackage{eurosym}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{siunitx}

\DeclareSIUnit{\EUR}{\text{\euro}}

\sisetup{ 
            output-decimal-marker={,},
            group-separator={.},
            group-minimum-digits=4,
}

\begin{document}

1) Calculate the \textbf{present value} needed to obtain 1\,400 € after 5 years at 6\% compound interest.

\vspace{1em}\par
\textbf{Solution:}

    \begin{enumerate}[itemsep=-3pt]
        \item $i = 6\% \Leftrightarrow q = 1,06$
        \item $n = 5$
        \item $FV = 1.400$
        \item $PV = FV \cdot q^{-n} \Rightarrow PV = \underline{\SI{1046,16}{\EUR}}$
    \end{enumerate}

\vspace{1em}\par
2) Calculate the \textbf{interest rate} required to turn 1\,000 € into 1\,400 € within 5 years.

\vspace{1em}\par
\textbf{Solution:}

    \begin{enumerate}[itemsep=-3pt]
        \item $n = 5$
        \item $PV = 1.000$
        \item $FV = 1.400$
        \item $i = \left(\frac{FV}{PV}\right)^{\frac{1}{n}}-1 \Rightarrow i = \underline{6,96\%}$
    \end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Load the `icomma` package.

Comment: And just like that, one problem solved … Thanks, it worked!

Comment: Regarding the math, there is a [noto sans math](https://github.com/notofonts/math) (not really complete) that might [work better](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syc58.png) than mathastext.